# Transfer of file between virtual machines

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, wget, file-transfer

I have a Xen based virtual machine which was created using command line and has no console. I intend to run the netio benchmark on that machine. However I am not able to get the netio132.zip folder onto the virtual machine.

I have tried

```
wget http://www.ars.de/ars/ars.nsf/f24a6a0b94c22d82862566960071bf5a/aa577bc4be573b05c125706d004c75b5/$FILE/netio132.zip
```

...which gives output as bad connection.

Also for using ftp and ssh, i do not have the password of the virtual machine.
So is there a way in which I can get my netio.zip onto the virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, use `netcat` also known as `nc`. Google it, it's easy.

Comment: Since I am using netio to evaluate KVM,i would need the same netio for evaluation of XEN. So unfortunately other benchmarks are of no use

Comment: Thank you. I kind of misunderstood what you meant.But was able to get it done using the nc command